# Return User to Requested URL after Authentication Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory

I am retrofitting a legacy Webforms project to use Azure AD for authentication. I have a startup.cs created with a ConfigureAuth and the app is registered in Azure. Everything works with the authentication, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation about setting a return URL. Azure has you set reply URLs, but those go to the home page. That's great if the user is navigating to the home page, but if they are going to /example-page, I want them to get redirected back to that instead of the home page.

In short, when a user navigates to example.com/example-page, I want them to be redirected to example.com/example-page after authentication rather than to example.com.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the authorization request you can pass a custom parameter.
You could handle "state" or "nonce" in this way:

1. Generate a random `UNIQUE_ID`
2. Put a `key` in the `Session` with an object that contains this ID and the current page url (that will be the `returnUrl`)
3. Pass the `UNIQUE_ID` in the authorization request like this:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/authorize?client_id=ef92a29b-b332-9d43-1341-23326315fa42&response_type=id_token+token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftest-babel.azurewebsites.net%2Fcallback.html&nonce=678910&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F&state=**[UNIQUE_ID]**

4. When you will receive the response on the `redirect_uri` you should receive back the `UNIQUE_ID`
5. Look for you custom `key` in the `Session` and if present (it should), first check if `UNIQUE_ID` matches the response one, then sign in the user, then retrieve the `returnUrl` and do the redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Redirect URI` with the specific page in the portal, then in your authentication url, specify the `redirect_uri` with that page, it will redirect to the page after authentication.

1.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> select your app in `App registrations` -> `Authentication`, set the redirect url e.g. `https://test.azurewebsites.net/callback.html`.

[image]

2.In your authorization URL, set the `redirect_uri` with `https://test.azurewebsites.net/callback.html` (url encoded), note the url must be one of the `Redirect URIs` in the portal.

Sample:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/authorize
?client_id=ef92a29b-b332-9d43-1341-23326315fa42
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2ftest-babel.azurewebsites.net%2Fcallback.html
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid hard coding callback urls and instead have the user redirected back to wherever they were trying to go before being authenticated.I suppose I'll have to create a callback url that looks for a destination in a cookie or something similar.

Comment: As of 2023, you don't need to implement custom code to archive return to the originally requested URL, which works out of the box, if you follow the instructions from the MS document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-web-app-aspnet-sign-in