# Azure AD Authentication Return To Previous Page With Parameter After Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I've searched it and my question is similar to this
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149732/return-user-to-requested-url-after-authentication-azure-ad)
but unfortunately, there is no answer.

The flow I want to implement:

1. When an unauthorized user enters
   https://test.com/testId=123
   (123 is not static)
2. Redirect to Azure AD authentication page and login success
3. Return to
   https://test.com/testId=123

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Core? Or some other framework?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is asp.net mvc (C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to implement the authentication logic yourself by creating requests to these endpoints:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Then redirect to the static URI that you set in the portal and code, just follow the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57174625/13308381).

If you want to redirect to the dynamic URI, Azure AD doesn't support it. Refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#redirect-uris-can-now-contain-query-string-parameters) bellow:

> Azure AD applications can now register and use redirect (reply) URIs
> with static query parameters (such as
> https://contoso.com/oauth2?idp=microsoft) for OAuth 2.0 requests.
> Dynamic redirect URIs are still forbidden as they represent a security
> risk, and this cannot be used to retain state information across an
> authentication request - for that, use the state parameter.